# Java - Hibernate - HQL Query fails from Query Editor. But runs successfully from the Swing Application - WHY?

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, netbeans

I am trying my first hello world application in Java Swing - Hibernate using Netbeans IDE.

1. I created a database and a table in SQL.
2. In Netbeans IDE, I connected the database service.
3. In my Java Swing Application, I have created the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file, hibernate mapping file and `hibernate.reveg.xml` file.
4. I tried to run a simple query in `HQL` Query Editor by right clicking the `.cfg` file and choosing Run HQL query.

The query I have tried - `from Batchjob`

Output window displayed error message.

> org.hibernate.MappingException: An association from the table
>   ProdTrendTest refers to an unmapped class: hibernate.sql.ProdTrend    at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(Configuration.java:1805)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1739)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1424)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)

Tried to copy the same query in my Swing project and used the below method.

```
private static String QUERY_BASED_ON_FIRST_NAME="from Batchjob";

-----
executeHQLQuery(QUERY_BASED_ON_FIRST_NAME);
```

***My question - Why will a query run successfully from the project but fail from the HQL Query Editor ?***

Comment: Do you have mapping of ProdTrendTest hbm file in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Sounds like you either have the Entity not defined properly in your Hibernate config file or you used the wrong name

Comment: @javafan, yes. The mapping is defined. If not, how will it work successfully when run from application ?

Comment: @Ascalonian, can you provide some more details on what is Entity ? and how it impacts only the HQL Query editor and not the query while run from swing application.

Comment: @Prem - An Entity it pretty much the POJO that represents the table you're querying. Check out [Mapping Entities](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html)

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?